# openvpn restricting clients from accessing certain IP's in internet with ufw

Tags: iptables, firewall, openvpn, ufw

I'am looking for a solution which can block openvpn clients in accessing certain website(ip's) in internet, i tried ufw rules like below , but doesnt seems to work from client, 
what piece do i miss?

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       xx.xx.xx.xx             
8.8.8.8                    DENY        10.8.0.80                 

8.8.8.8                    DENY OUT    Anywhere on tun0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying problem was with existing iptable's entry by the cloud provider .

Resolved by safely clearing the iptables without getting self-lockout , then adding the rules from scratch .

also used iptables instead the wrapping ufw

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.8.0.80 -i tun0 -d 1.1.1.1 -o eth0 -j DROP
```